# Distributed Infinispan Cache as Hibernate L2 Cache Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, distributed, infinispan

I would like to create an application, where I would use Hibernate L2 Cache to reduce the unnecessity to always requesting database for data.

In my application, over 80% of the time would be READ operation, and less than 20% would be Create / Update / Delete Operation. Therefore I think using Hibernate L2 Cache would be beneficial. However, as we are going to horizontal scale the application, we would like to use Infinispan as the L2 Cache of Hibernate.

However there are several questions which we are uncertain of.

1. If I understand correctly, Hibernate L2 Cache should work by updating the cache, whenever there is a new create / update / delete operation, or when the query has not yet queried previously. Therefore on a multiple servers setup connecting to the same database, since there are network IO issue, how could multiple update operation works in such environment? As the 2 application server may update the database simultaneously, each update the same entity to different data, but due to network IO issue, how could Hibernate know this data should be cached and synced, and this data should not?

Comment: For each question, the answer is: it depends of what you wish. If you could improve the question saying what you are expecting, I can try to help you with the Infinispan configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of cache you are using. An invalidation cache, which I would suggest you to use here, will just invalidate cache entries that are stale. A replicating cache would replicate the changes to each node in the cluster. Hibernate just asks the cache implementation for the cache entry and if the cache returns that, it will use that and avoid accessing the database. If the cache entry is stale or how much blocking is involved in that cache lookup depends on the transaction configuration of the cache.